# socket.io not receiving messages from server

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Very simple:

I want to connect to my server, then write some stuff in a form, hit submit, parse it on the server side, and send back an acknowledgement.

everything works, except the last acknowledgement message. it just seems not to reach the client. the function is never executed, and i have no idea why

server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var httpServer = require('http').Server(app);
var ioServer = require('socket.io')(httpServer);

function saveConfigToFile(config) {

    if (config) {
        var data = JSON.stringify(config);

        fs.writeFile('./public/config.json', data, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('[ERROR] Error while saving config file!');
                console.log(err.message);
                return;
            }
            console.log('Config file updated');
            ioServer.emit('info', {msg:'config_saved'});
        })
    }
}
```

client:

```
socket = new io.connect();

socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log("connected");
});

socket.on('info', function(data) {
    console.log("check");
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

Server console says "config file updated", if i click save.

Browser console says "connected" (on page load).

But "check" (or the message/data) is never printed... what could be the reason?

Comment: What is `ioServer`? Could you include the code where it is defined.

Comment: sure, i just edited it into the server code

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the snippet of code. I tried setting up a simple socket.io application and it all seems to work fine. Have you tried commenting some lines to try and narrow down to the offending line?

Comment: sure i have, but i don't know what to look for. because i am also thinking that it SHOULD work.... hm :/

Comment: ok this is crazy... i changed nothing (that i know of) and it just works.....
really strange...